# About "id" of strategy.entry function

Tags: pine-script

```
num = 1
id_name = num == 1 ? "buy1" : num == 2 ? "buy2" : string(na)
strategy.entry(id=id_name, long=strategy.long)
```

I don't know why this scripy gets error..
Do I always put id in const string?
Does anyone have some good idea?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a mutable variable as the input for the `id` of the [strategy.entry()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dentry) function.

Excerpt from the reference manual of [strategy.entry()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dentry):
***id (string)** A required parameter. The order identifier.*

**id (string)** means that it must be a constant.
If it would've said **id (series[string])**, then you could've used mutable variables.